# What does "you have twitches to-night" mean?

Tags: idioms

What does *"You have twitches tonight"* mean?

I am thinking this is some kind of idioms but i can't guess the meaning.

Comment: It's not an idiom that I've heard before.  Can you tell us were you found that phrase?  Maybe the context will help

Comment: It's from a book I read. it goes : Mrs. Jones eyeing him sharply.“You have the twitches to-night. Anything wrong?”

Comment: it probably means that he's twitching more than usual, or that he looks nervous

Comment: I see, looks nervous then

Comment: Please add the title and author of the book, as well as the page number. Knowing what book this is may make a difference to the answer, as languages change over time. If *to-night* is quoted accurately, that suggests relatively archaic English.

Comment: When quoting a phrase, you should make sure to quote it *exactly*, including hyphenation. `twitches-tonight` doesn't mean much to anyone, but `twitches to-night` is easily recognisable as `twitches` followed by the archaic `to-night` for `tonight`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence most likely means

> You're twitching (or nervous)today

---

It's using the same syntax that you would use if you were to tell someone that they had a disease or condition.

When someone tells you that you have a disease they will normally say

> You have *[disease name]*

for instance:

> You have *the flu.*

---

If one were to make up a word for the condition of twitching a lot, *the twitches* is a word that might come up, and that's probably what the author of that book did